# FreeBSD 11.4 | PKG GDB92

Tags: package, gdb, freebsd

i want to install "gdb92" on my FreeBSD Server 11.4, i have already another Server (11.4) with this package -> "gdb-9.2_1 GNU GDB of newer version than comes with the system".
But when i type #pkg search gdb, i'll only find the gdb-10.1_1 package.
Can anyone explain me why?

Best Regards
ZP

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the gdb port was updated to 10.1:

https://cgit.freebsd.org/ports/commit/devel/gdb?id=2c2f3a710a6f3dec972ceb92c3f93fca455f24ef

and so the new packages were built from this.

Comment: Is there any solution to get the gdb-9.2_1 package now?
I need this version really

Comment: @ZypesProduction There is a way--I've read about others who do--but I don't know how.